# Validate a JSON to be Serializable to Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

Is there is any way in C# to make sure that json is serializable to Dictionary? One possible solution be use try catch in,

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Is there is any better way?

Comment: Using try-catch is a good solution unless you have other issues.

Comment: no it's not,  try-catch is never a good if case

Comment: as much as i understand you can take a look at the class to Deserialize and check if it implement the necessary attributes, right? (i'm not a json expert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [JSON Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON_Schema) for validation.  There is a [demo page here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/schema.aspx) (the link is from [this article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/01/04/json-net-3-5-beta-2-json-schema-validation.aspx)).  Same principle as an XML schema.

Comment: Thanks but I need to validate dictionary. Json should only include a single key/value object and nothing else. Can you show me schema regarding this?

Comment: @user960567 Can you perhaps show a simple example of Json that is acceptable to you and Json that is not?  I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: @user960567 Your example is not json. Am I missing something? I'm sorry if I have completely misunderstood you, but you say you have json, but then show an example that is not json. If the problem is that you don't know if you receive json at all, and your method is not time critical, then try-catch should work fine.

Comment: I need only dictionary. That's it. So it's simple json object.